# I am stuck with modal: How to put text inside of one

Tags: java, jquery, html, modal-dialog, dreamweaver

Total noob here.

I am in the process of building my hobby website and feel that I could, with some hard work, create a fully functional site. However, I am rather stuck on modal popout window.

I understand the basics of getting one to work, i.e. download jquery or related java library, attach said library to webpage in the  section. Apply modal popout in similar way making sure to include the CSS for it.

I can get it to function in my site, so with Shadowbox I managed to get it to actually popout. Where I am stuck, with Shadowbox in particular, is actually putting stuff inside the modal popout. I am really only interesting putting text in the modal popout with maybe a link or small picture to compliment the text.

What is hindering me is my lack of knowledge. This may be either a lack of understanding with regards to class attributes or href attributes, or a lack of knowledge. The only progression I have made with this is simply because of the copy and paste, and some image path manipulation with Shadowbox. I am still horribly confused as to how the script activates, what tags/attributes I need to make to ensure data within a  is included in the modal popout window.

I would really like to have a modal popout like this http://typedeskref.com/ but feel that this is far, far beyond me.

In summary: I don't know how to put text/images inside of a modal popout. I don't know how a modal popout is activated and how to ensure I can control what is kept inside of it. The reason why I say this is because the limited sucess I have had with Shadow box is because it has somehow managed to pick up everything that is on my site, images, links etc. So when the modal popout is opened, there is my site, in modal form.

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I really appreciate any help or advice you can give me. Even a shove in the direction where such information can be located would be great!

p.s. I am using dreamweaver cs5

Comment: too length to read, you should be more precise to your problem

Comment: its pretty easy to do , the link you used and popups they used are not very complex , its simply a div absolutely postioned thats it , let me know what exactly do you want , i can guide you

Comment: Sorry it is a bit long really. Basically I want to have a modal popout and I don't know how to get one working. I have manged to make one popout but don't know how to add text to it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how crazy and amazing you want your dialogs to be.  It could be something as simple as downloading jQuery UI Dialogs (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and then doing this.

```
<div id="dialog">Hello</div>
<a id="button1">One</a>
<a id="button2">Two</a>

// Do the setup when the page has loaded
$(function() {

   // Create the dialog, don't show it on page load
   $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen:false});

   // Button One will show the dialog
   $("#button1").click(function() { $("#dialog").dialog("open"); });

   // Button Two changes the content, THEN shows the dialog.
   $("#button2").click(function() { 
       $("#dialog").html("Goodbye");
       $("#dialog").dialog("open");
   });
});
```

It's a starting point.  Same dialog, changing the content, triggered by clicking a link.  That library has all manner of options (animations, etc) and you can style it to whatever look-and-feel you like.

Here is a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/dYMvH/